# VSCode test debugging doesn't use launch.json args

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, django-testing

Using VSCode, I'm trying to configure `launch.json` with django's test debugging (the default unittest one doesn't create test databases), but running test with debugger doesn't use the specified args in the `launch.json`.

launch.json:

```json
       {
            "name": "Django Testing",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "purpose": ["debug-test"],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "test",
                "api.tests"
            ],
            "django": true,
            "justMyCode": true
        }
```

I configured `"purpose": ["debug-test"]` according to the docs so that when I click debug tests, it will run `manage.py test api.tests` in the terminal. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_debug-tests, (Debug tests section)

When I click the start button in the `Run and Debug` toolbar, the expected behaviour occurs.

```
 C:\Users\61403\Desktop\liner> c: && cd c:\Users\61403\Desktop\liner && cmd /C "c:\Users\61403\Desktop\liner\venv\Scripts\python.exe c:\Users\61403\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.10.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher 62791 
-- C:\Users\61403\Desktop\liner\manage.py test api.tests "
```

VSCode runs `...\manage.py\test api.tests` in the terminal.

However, when I run `Test: Debug All Tests` (What I want to work) from the command pallette, I get this:

```
C:\Users\61403\Desktop\liner> c: && cd c:\Users\61403\Desktop\liner && cmd /C "c:\Users\61403\Desktop\liner\venv\Scripts\python.exe c:\Users\61403\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.10.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher 62817 
-- c:\Users\61403\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.10.1\pythonFiles\visualstudio_py_testlauncher.py --us=. --up=test*.py --uvInt=2 --result-port=62814 -tapi.tests.CompanyTestCase.test_creating_company_creates_queue -tapi.tests.QueueTestCase.test_join_queue_endpoint -tapi.tests.QueueTestCase.test_position_in_queue -tapi.tests.UserTestCase.test_vscode_test -tapi.tests.CompanyTestCase.test_creating_company_creates_queue -tapi.tests.QueueTestCase.test_join_queue_endpoint -tapi.tests.QueueTestCase.test_position_in_queue -tapi.tests.UserTestCase.test_vscode_test --testFile=c:\Users\61403\Desktop\liner\api\tests.py "
```

VSCode doesn't do `manage.py test api.tests` but instead runs every test within my test case individually.

Am I missing something, and how can I fix this?

**Edit:**
Minimal Reproducible Example:

Start a fresh django project called testing. Create an app called aif,

Within the aif directory create the following

tests.py

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from django import setup
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testing.settings")
setup()

from aif.models import SomeModel

# Create your tests here.

class Test_My_Case(TestCase):
    
    def test_some_test(self):

        SomeModel.objects.create()
        my_queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()
        assert len(SomeModel.objects.all()) == 1
```

models.py

```py
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    pass
```

run `py manage.py makemigrations` and `py manage.py migrate`

Then configure VSCode's tester: Configure Tests > unittest > test*.py

Then in the launch.json add the following configurations.

```json
 {
            "name": "Django Tests",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "purpose": ["debug-test"],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
            "args": [
                "test",
                "aif.tests"
            ],
            "django": true,
            "justMyCode": true
        },
```

Now:

In the Run and Debug VSCode toolbar, configure to use Django Tests (the config you just created in launhc.json). Run the debugger. Look at the `output` and see that it runs

```
cmd /C "C:\Users\61403\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe c:\Users\61403\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.10.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher 57709 -- C:\Users\61403\Desktop\testing\manage.py test aif.tests "
```

Note the last part `test aif.tests`

In the Testing VSCode toolbar. `tests` should be discovered. Click the icon for debug test. Look in the output section, and you find this.

```
DAP Server launched with command: C:\Users\61403\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe c:\Users\61403\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.10.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @JialeDu I just added an edit with the minimal reproducible example, thanks

Comment: I tested it according to your description. But maybe it's an environmental issue that I didn't succeed on my machine. But debugging and testing are two different things. So they can have two different panels. Also, you can try to test with `py manage.py test` in terminal.

Comment: @JialeDu Hmm maybe so. In any case, I my main reason for wanting to do this was difficulty configuring unittest with django, and I have now switched to pytest so I won't need to edit launch.json for test debugging. Thank you for trying to help anyways